# Wheel slips and weight

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, friction, rotational-kinematics

With rainy season starting, I have been thinking about traction and have a question:

**Question**: If two identical vehicles, one of mass $m$ and the other of mass $2m$ are starting from rest with equal acceleration, which vehicle's wheels are more likely to slip assuming no deformation of the tire?

I have been wondering about this
and I'm thinking that the heavier vehicle's tires would have more friction because of *increased normal force* and because the *angular acceleration of both is equal*, the heavier vehicle is less likely to slip. Can someone please help me put this into equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may be useful.  You basically stated the entire relationship which is:

$$
F_{friction}=\mu N 
$$

where $\mu$ is the coefficient of static friction between tire and road and $N$ is the normal force.  If we assume each tire gets $1/4$ the vehicle weight, then:

$$
F_{friction}=\mu N = \mu \frac{mg}{4} 
$$

where $m$ is the mass of the vehicle, and $g$ is the acceleration of gravity.

Thus, as the mass increases, the maximum possible static friction force increases.  If this force is exceeded then we get into slippage.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @ad2004, for your information, the SE network as a whole, and Physics.SE in particular have a policy that we users should refrain from using taglines or sign-offs in our posts. See e. g.  [our help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), [a discussion in our Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/360/149907) and [a discussion in the mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/816175).